# glUseProgram(0) takes 50ms?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Are there any reasons a call to disable a glsl program should take 50ms?

I did a glFlush before, so it can't be the pipeline being flushed before a program change.

Enabling the shader takes 0.03ms.

Comment: Does it change if you call glFinish instead of glFlush?

Comment: The pusher robot is protecting your pipeline.

Comment: What is your platform ? 50ms is far from a normal timing. Could the rendering done before the glUseProgram possibly take 50ms to execute?

Answer (score 3):

Just guessing - if you are working in a compatibility-enabled GL context, disabling the GLSL program may invoke an Fixed-Function Pipeline (FFP) program construction based on the FFP GL state at the current moment.